# Import virtualBox appliance to KVM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Im new using KVM as a virtualization solution. Currently I'm using VirtualBox to manage my virtual machines in my personal computer, but I'm moving my virtualization to a Server, so I set up a Linux server with KVM. And now I'm trying to import a virtualBox vm to KVM.

So far I couldn't make it work. I already convert the ova file from VirtualBox to a format more familiar to KVM (qcow2), and I try to create a new virtual machine using virt-install command and setting the new virtual machine hard drive with the .qcow2 file.

There is anyone could help me?

thank you!

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you unless your provide some details. What virt-install command did you run? How is it failing?

Comment: What is target distribution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually create the domain XML file, just create a new domain xml. Here's an  [Example domain XML configuration](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US//Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/section-libvirt-dom-xml-example.html) (the second one) from Fedora project.

Or you can use the GUI tool named `virt-manager` to import the converted qcow2 file step by step. Please install this tool via command `sudo yum install virt-manager` if using RHEL/Fedora